# Combine imputed and non imputed data

Tags: r, merge, r-mice

I have a question about merging datasets after multiple imputation. I have created an example to explain my problem:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
age <- c(60,NA,90,55,60,61,77,67,88,90)
bmi <- c(30,NA,NA,23,24,NA,27,23,26,21)
time <- c(62,88,85,NA,68,62,89,62,70,99)
dat <- data.frame(id, age, bmi, time)
dat

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
m1 <- c(60,78,90,55,60,61,77,67,88,90)
m2 <- c(30,44,35,23,24,22,27,23,26,21)
m3 <- c(62,88,85,78,68,62,89,62,70,99)
dat2 <- data.frame(id, m1, m2, m3)
dat2
```

I have two datasets, dat and dat2. The dataset dat contains missing variables, so I use multiple imputation to impute this dataset (package MICE):

```
library(mice)
impdat <- mice(dat, maxit = 0)
methdat <- impdat$method
preddat <- impdat$predictorMatrix
preddat["id",] <- 0
preddat[,"id"] <- 0
impdat <- mice(dat, method = methdat, predictorMatrix = preddat, seed =         
2018, maxit = 10, m = 5)
```

Now I want to merge the imputed dataset impdat with the dataset dat2. But that is were my problem arises. I tried the following:

```
completedat <- complete(impdat, include = T, action = 'long')
finaldat <- merge(completedat, dat2, by = "id")

finaldat <- as.mids(finaldat)
  Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, j, value = c(61, 88)) : replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

However, this gives me an error message. The merging is successful, because the dataframe completedat is what I want. The problem is that I cannot transform it back to a mids object.

I know I can add the variables from dat2 one by one. That does work:

```
completedat <- complete(impdat, include = T, action = 'long')
completedat$m1 <- dat2$m1
finaldat2 <- as.mids(completedat)
```

In this example, this is okay, because dat2 only has 4 variables. In my real data, I have approximately 200 variables that I want to add to my multiple imputed dataset, so I hope there is an easier way to add all those variables to my imputed dataset. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `cbind` work provided that you want to combine imputed and non-imputed data?

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
age <- c(60,NA,90,55,60,61,77,67,88,90)
bmi <- c(30,NA,NA,23,24,NA,27,23,26,21)
time <- c(62,88,85,NA,68,62,89,62,70,99)
dat <- data.frame(id, age, bmi, time)
dat

id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
m1 <- c(60,78,90,55,60,61,77,67,88,90)
m2 <- c(30,44,35,23,24,22,27,23,26,21)
m3 <- c(62,88,85,78,68,62,89,62,70,99)
dat2 <- data.frame(id, m1, m2, m3)
dat2

# install.packages("mice")
library(mice)
impdat <- mice(dat, 
               seed = 2018, 
               maxit = 10, 
               m = 5)
impdat
# Class: mids
# Number of multiple imputations:  5 
# Imputation methods:
#   id   age   bmi  time 
# "" "pmm" "pmm" "pmm" 
# PredictorMatrix:
#   id age bmi time
# id    0   1   1    1
# age   1   0   1    1
# bmi   1   1   0    1
# time  1   1   1    0

impdat = complete(impdat)
impdat

# id age bmi time
# 1   1  60  30   62
# 2   2  60  24   88
# 3   3  90  24   85
# 4   4  55  23   89
# 5   5  60  24   68
# 6   6  61  24   62
# 7   7  77  27   89
# 8   8  67  23   62
# 9   9  88  26   70
# 10 10  90  21   99

final_data = cbind(impdat, dat2)
final_data
# id age bmi time id m1 m2 m3
# 1   1  60  30   62  1 60 30 62
# 2   2  60  24   88  2 78 44 88
# 3   3  90  24   85  3 90 35 85
# 4   4  55  23   89  4 55 23 78
# 5   5  60  24   68  5 60 24 68
# 6   6  61  24   62  6 61 22 62
# 7   7  77  27   89  7 77 27 89
# 8   8  67  23   62  8 67 23 62
# 9   9  88  26   70  9 88 26 70
# 10 10  90  21   99 10 90 21 99
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue. In my case, I had a different number of observations between my imputed and non-imputed data sets. To fix this, after I merged the data, I then re-coded the variable `.id`. The `mice` package outputs `.id` when you call `mice` and `complete(..., action = 'long')`. This is different from your data frame variable `id` but they should correspond to each other by the following code.

```
library(dplyr)
# recode .id based on value of id
mydata <- mutate(mydata, .id = as.numeric(as.factor(id)))
# this step is important according to the mice manual
mydata <- mydata[order(mydata$.imp, mydata$.id),]
```

The `as.mids` function worked for me when I applied this recode and I hope it works for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the prettiest method, but it worked for me:

When your imputed database has a different number of rows, you can use full_join(). Include all the variables (such as patient id), except for the imputed variable, with by. The imputed variable will then appear is variable.x and variable.y. Then imput when the value is NA, see code below:

```
new_db <- full_join(db1,db2,by=c("xx","yy"))


# Check the number of NA's (imputed variable name is imputed in this example)
summary(new_db$imputed.x)
summary(new_db$imputed.y)

new_db$imputed.x[ is.na(new_db$imputed.x) ] <- new_db$imputed.y[ is.na(new_db$imputed.x) ]


#With the following code you can easily check for NA values: 
sapply(db,function(x)sum(is.na(x)))
```